# bazel-bin hosted python process seemingly can't find its hosting zip file

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to get a TensorFlow example (`textsum`) to run, and the `readme.md` specifies to use `bazel` to do the training. Ok, I dutifully installed `chocolaty` and then `bazel`, and then `bazel` ran and created the build files successfully. So `bazel` seems to work.

However when I got to the train step - also orchestrated by `bazel` - it choked with an `IOError` message that I don't really understand and can't find much information about.

Here it is:

```
UXIE+mike@uxie  /d/tensorflow/models
$ bazel-bin/textsum/seq2seq_attention     --mode=train     --article_key=article     --abstract_key=abstract     
--data_path=data/training-*     --vocab_path=data/vocab     --log_root=textsum/log_root     --train_dir=textsum/log_root/train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "bazel-bin\textsum\seq2seq_attention\__main__.py", line 168, in <module>
  File "bazel-bin\textsum\seq2seq_attention\__main__.py", line 115, in Main
  File "bazel-bin\textsum\seq2seq_attention\__main__.py", line 98, in CreateModuleSpace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\?\\bazel-bin\\textsum\\seq2seq_attention'
```

I am running this on Windows 10 in a bash shell (have tried a couple - same results everytime) and it is clearly successfully starting the python code contained in the `seq2set_attention` zip file (see the *2nd line* that invokes that file).

However looking at the error dump it seems to get confused and suddenly it can't find that zip file anymore (see the *last line*).

So a few questions:

- I don't remember seeing that `\\\\?\\` prefix before. Googling for that string didn't help. I would like to know what it means exactly.
- Why can't the executable suddenly not find the zip file it is hosted in? (if that is indeed what is happening)
- Finally if you have an idea of what configuration step I might have missed, I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Bazel 0.4.5, see https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2708

You can build Bazel from HEAD or upgrade it to 0.5.0 release candidate to fix this.

```
choco install bazel --version 0.5.0-rc6
```

Comment: That fixed it, although I had to put my files all on the C: drive too, having it on D: seemed to cause a similar error. I am using Anaconda 4.1.1 64-bit (pyhton 3.5.2) and bazel installs a standard python 2.7 as well in case anyone is interested. All rather confused...

Comment: What exact error did you get when building from D:? Do you mind filing a bug on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues?  You can skip the installation of python 2.7 when using chocolatey, just point BAZEL_PYTHON to the python3.exe in Anaconda.

Comment: It was pretty much the same error. But throw in an upvote and I will see if I can get a repro and document it in github. Tomorrow though - stopping work now.